# Meaning of negative mutual information

Tags: information-theory

From wiki, I know negative multiple mutual information exists. But I can't understand its meaning. Does someone help me have a better understand? For example, if I have three variables which have negative mutual information, if they have a lower mutual information, what's it mean?

Comment: Were you reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_mutual_information#Synergy_and_redundancy)? It not only explains how this can happen, it tries to explain its interpretation in the context of a logic gates example.

Comment: I read it again carefully. I think I understand the meaning. Thank you very much.

Answer (score -2):

Mutual information (MI) measures how much two variables are inter-dependent.
So, higher the MI, more similar the variables.

Two variables could be, for example, the intensity values of two greyscale images.
But many algorithms use the matching *cost*, i.e. how much two variables are different. Hence, the minus sign.